# Bootstrap3 - ensuring data grouped correctly in responsive grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve the following layout in Bootstrap 3, converting an old table based layout to Bootstrap's responsive grid:

```
label1a: value1a    label2: value2
label1b: value1b    label3: value3
label1c: value1c    label4: value4
```

With 1a through c being related data that needs to be grouped together, in this case address data, e.g.

```
Address1: [data1]    Contact:  Joe Bloggs
Town:     [data2]    Position: Developer
```

etc.

Problem I have is at smaller viewports I want the address data to remain displayed in a single section rather than interspersed with the other data, i.e.

```
Address1:
[data1]
Town: 
[data2]
Contact:
Joe Bloggs
Position:
Developer
```

but it is coming out as

```
Address1:
[data1]
Contact:
Joe Bloggs
Town: 
[data2]
Position:
Developer
```

This is not surprising given the code:

```
                    <div class="row">                         
                             <label for="Address" class="control-label col-sm-2">Address:</label>     
                            <div class="col-sm-4"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address1")%> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address2") %></div>                         
                             <label for="Contact" class="control-label col-sm-2">Contact:</label>     
                            <div class="col-sm-4"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></div>                                                 
                     </div>    

                     <div class="row">
                             <label for="Town" class="control-label col-sm-2">Town:</label>     
                            <div class="col-sm-4"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Address3")%></div>
                             <label for="Position" class="control-label col-sm-2">Position:</label>     
                            <div class="col-sm-4"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Position")%></div>                        
                      </div>
```

This must be a fairly common scenario so hopefully something simple. I can obviously workaround and change the layout but it would be good to know how best to achieve this in Bootstrap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a row with 2 columns. One column for the address info, the other column for the remaining info.

Then by using bootstrap's built in form layout, you can have the text drop below the label automatically on mobile devices.

Here's an example bootply: http://www.bootply.com/l2lxFK0bCV

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Address 1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p class="form-control-static">123 Main St</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Town</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p class="form-control-static">London</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Contact</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p class="form-control-static">Joe Bloggs</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Position</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p class="form-control-static">Developer</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```